# Problem to rewrite an old URL to a new one in IIS manager and web.config file

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm here in last resort. So here is my problem,
At work my boss asked me to rewrite an URL to be more user friendly.

The old pattern is this one: `https://{hostServer}/SiteName/index.html`

The new one should be this one: `https://maps.swcs.be`

But i looked in the doc of IIS, looked in here for some more informations etc...

I learned, it's done in the web.config file at the root of the repo "wwwroot" So I wrote my rule in there

here it is

```
<system.webServer>      
  <rule name="redirection d'url">
    <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{https://maps.swcs.be}" type="Pattern" pattern="Ëxpertises[0-9]\index\.html">
      </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://maps.swcs.be" />
  </rule>
</system.webServer>
```

I tried the `<action type="Redirect" ...>` too and other stuff but it's the only one that returned something... the IISstart.htm file

I'm pretty new to URL redirection, if one of you could enligthen me that would be awesome

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Go through the examples Microsoft showed in the documentation, so that you start to really know how regular expressions and the settings work, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module. 2. Learn how to use FRT to debug the rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Mind your words. If you really spend enough time on the articles and examples, you shouldn't have used an invalid condition in the rule.

Comment: Sorry for my word I was really tired of it ^^ anyway I found an other way, with the meta tag in an html file, Thanks for the tips, I will dig more in this field to really understand what I messed up ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend that you read the documentation provided by lex li in detail, which can help you fully understand how to use url rewrite.

Secondly, I want to know your initial url and rewritten url, you don’t have to show the correct url, just an example. Such as initial url is `http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/index` and rewritten url is `http://example.com/index`

So I assume your initial url is `https://{hostServer}/SiteName/index.html` and rewritten url is `https://maps.swcs.be`.
[image]
[image]

This rule will match the uri, if the uri is /SiteName/index.html, it will redirect to `https://maps.swcs.be`. You can also change antion type to rewrite. If you choose rewirte, nothing will happen when you check url in browser. But redirect will make the url change to new one in browser.

Comment: Allright thanks for the answer, I read the docs provided by Lex Li and even his articles, I understood the principle and we found a solution here at work, an ugly one. I changed the meta tag in the html file but my boss wants to keeps the URL maps.swcs.be in the browser not the redirected one. I found out, it's a 301 redirect. 

So to say it simply, maps.swcs.be should redirect to my page https://ServerName/Example/index.html

Comment: You can use rewrite to keep maps.swcs.be in browser like this<rule name="redirection">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="maps.swcs.be" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://ServerName/Example/index.html" />
                </rule>

Comment: If your solution can work, please post it as answer so that can help others with similar problems.

Comment: Sorry Zhang, it doesn't wwork, I tried your rule and the html tag together, it redirect me correctly but it doesn't keep the URL like I want... I swear I'm cursed ^^

Comment: It's ok. The new rule is rewrite not redirect. What's the url you want to keep? Could you describe the effect you want to achieve in detail, because you keep mentioning the html tag. You'd better clear cookie and cache before enter the url in browser. If it still cannot keep url, I suggest you enable fail request tracing to check the process.

Comment: Hi Zang, sorry for the delay, I had'nt any computer with me this week-end, anyway. 

My task is to use maps.swcs.be as an URL for our agents, instead of the URL https://ServerName/example/index.hmtl.
maps.swcs.be should be the URL leading me to the second, and she should stay in the browser searchbar instead of the other.

By default maps.swcs.be redirect me to iisstart.htm page, so in that page I changed the meta tag in the header so it redirect me where I want. It's a workaround
If I try to write a new rule in IIS manager, I feel it's not took in account

Comment: According to your description, I think this rewriting rule meets your needs. Please note that rewriting is not a redirection. The redirection will keep the url you entered in the browser.Url rewriting does not involve meta tags in html, so I don’t understand why you use it

Comment: I used it because no other solution worked ^^ but I know it's just a workaround we will try somethings tomorrow here at work, i will update here if we don't find ^^ thanks again for your time